# canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg") can't be used in .drawImage()

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, file-format, drawimage, todataurl

I am trying to capture a canvas screen using `canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg")` and then use it in `ctx.drawImage();`, but it gives the error "Uncaught TypeError" saying that the image format is not supported. Which format do

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(0,0, 100, 100);
ctx.fill();

const test = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");

ctx.fillStyle = "white";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(0,0, 100, 100);
ctx.fill();

ctx.drawImage(test, 0, 0); //Uncaught TypeError
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

I use in `.toDataURL()` to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `test` is a string.

```js
const image = new Image()
image.addEventListener('load', () => {
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0)
})
image.src = test
```

In context:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

ctx.beginPath()
ctx.rect(0, 0, 100, 100)
ctx.fill()

const test = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg')

ctx.fillStyle = 'white'
ctx.beginPath()
ctx.rect(0, 0, 100, 100)
ctx.fill()

const image = new Image()
image.addEventListener('load', () => {
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0)
})
image.src = test
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```